# Overload operator __mul__ python

Tags: python, oop, numpy, operator-overloading

i'm trying to implement `__mul__` on this example

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if type(other) in (int, float):
            return foo(self.data * other)
        else:
            return foo(self.data * other.data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   f1 = foo(10)
   f2 = foo(20)

   (f1*f2).data # 200
   (f1*50).data # 500
   (50*f1).data # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'instance'
```

however it does not work at `50 * f1`.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this you need the [`__rmul__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) method:

> These methods are called to implement the binary arithmetic operations (+, -, *, /, %, divmod(), pow(), **, <<, >>, &, ^, |) with reflected (swapped) operands.

In your case:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __mul__(self, other):
        # As before

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        # This will be called in the situation you brought up.
```

Comment: In this case, it's easy enough to just add `__rmul__ = __mul__` to the class definition (after  `__mul__` of course :-)

Comment: @mgilson That's an excellent point - many thanks. (I must confess I didn't get to think of the implementation, just how to get the method called).